# Initializationerror occured while executing the runner.java class to generate the step definition through cucumber without Maven

Tags: cucumber

### I have created the Java project and configure the cucumber into it.

```
 I have created the below directory:

 **features --> feature file
 functionlibrary--> StepDefinitions.java
 root --> Runner.java**

Imported the selenium & Cucumber jar files into the project

Here are the images of the project along with the error, please help me with the issue. ##
```

## [Feature File Image]

I am executing the feature file by the run as "cucumber feature"
Then below error occurred#
        Feature: Group Name

```
      Scenario: Access the Group page in an application
        Given User is on meetings Homepage
        When User click to Menu
        And Select the Group page
        Then Group page should display

      Scenario: Group saved, group exists with same initials
        Given User is on Group page
        When User search the group name
        And initials entered have been used in another group
        And Click to Save button
        Then the system will raise a validation error and not save the group

      Scenario: Group saved, group does not exist with same initials
        Given User is on Group page
        When User search the group name
        And initials entered have not been used in another group
        And Click to Save button
        Then the system will save the group as normal
```

# [Runner class]
 When executing the runner.java by right click --> Run as ---> JUnit
 Then Right side error occurred#

```
    package root;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features ="src/Features",glue = {"functionlibrary"})
    public class Runner {

    }
```

#[Step Definition]
 Currently, its blank, once the feature file executes successfully than on console output will come which will paste it under step definition.#

```
          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3lZC.png
          [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTZ8R.png
          [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSDwg.png
```

Comment: Maybe you miss this dependency  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-expressions.

Comment: Correction in grammar